# Creating correct BigDecimals from slightly off doubles

Tags: java, performance, double, rounding

I'm connecting to an external system that provides me with a stream of `double` financial prices. I know that the values I receive are meant to be decimal values, and that therefore [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) would have been a better choice, but the provided client library forces me to use `double` instead.

My goal is to build a `BigDecimal` from the provided `double` values. The simple solution is to just use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`. However, as is a common problem when working with `double`, the values that I receive look like `0.12000000001` instead of `0.12`, or `1.15999999998` instead of `1.16`. I could do some rounding by using `BigDecimal.setScale()`, but the problem with that is that I don't know the exact intended precision of the value.

**How can I reconstruct the intended decimal value?**

My solution so far relies on the fact that the value I receive is always within 1 or 2 ULP of the intended decimal value. So I just try converting the value I receive as well as the values 1-2 ulp up/down to `String`, and create a BigDecimal from the shortest of these strings.

```
    private static BigDecimal shortestBigDecimal(double inputDouble) {
        double ulp = Math.ulp(inputDouble);
        String center = Double.toString(inputDouble);
        String high = Double.toString(inputDouble + ulp);
        String low = Double.toString(inputDouble - ulp);
        String high2 = Double.toString(inputDouble + ulp + ulp);
        String low2 = Double.toString(inputDouble - ulp - ulp);

        String shortest = minLength(minLength(minLength(minLength(low2, low), center), high), high2);
        return new BigDecimal(shortest);
    }

    private static String minLength(String a, String b) {
        return a.length() < b.length() ? a : b;
    }
```

This code passes all of my test cases, but it creates a lot of temporary `String`s.

**Is there a more efficient way to do this?**

Comment: There are many rounding options in BigDecimal (see javadocs). In financial matters the money could be held with 2 decimals, but in tax calculations with 6 decimals. Then taking 6 would at least be correct data again (no 0.159999). Depends or your countries laws.

Comment: None of which work, because like I mentionned, I do not know ahead of time the intended number of decimals. So cutting off at a pre-determined number of decimals is not a good solution.

Comment: Rounding to the _maximum_ precision the (tax) law requires might be a pragmatic.

Comment: How do you as a human being know that 1.15999999998 was not the intended number (you already dismissed rounding to a fixed precision, e.g. 5 decimal places)? It could be a valid 11-places number instead of the 2-places-rounded 1.16. Before you expect a machine to make that decision, you have to be clear what you want from the machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overloaded [constructor of `BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(double,java.math.MathContext)) where you can provide a [`MathContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/MathContext.html). Using [`DECIMAL32`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/MathContext.html#DECIMAL32) we have a rather low precision (`7` decimal places), meaning everything out of the range is rounded using [`RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN). By using the method [`stripTrailingZeros`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros()), we can get only the significant digits and get rid of trailing `0`.

```
public static BigDecimal shortestBigDecimal(double inputValue) {
    return 
        new BigDecimal( 
            inputValue, 
            MathContext.DECIMAL32
        )
        .stripTrailingZeros();
}
```

Using this prints:

```
System.out.println(shortestBigDecimal(1.15999999998));    // 1.16
System.out.println(shortestBigDecimal(0.12000000000001)); // 0.12
```

Comment: It doesn't really work. The values I receive can have anywhere between 0 to 8 decimals, and I'd like to avoid losing precision as much as possible in case more decimals are required in the future. The point of this question is to find a way to avoid cutting off at a pre-determined number of decimals.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs could you please provide some more example data, with the expected output?

Comment: @LordOfThePigs would `BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.round(inputValue * 100000000), 8).stripTrailingZeros()` work better for you?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested an alternative approach that involves no strings at all. Instead, it searches for the lowest scale factor BigDecimal that results from rounding of the original value and is in the range:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public strictfp class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testit(0.1);
        testit(1.15999999998);
        testit(0.12000000000000001);
        testit(100.00001);
        testit(0.3);
        double ulp = Math.ulp(0.3);
        testit(0.3 + ulp);
        testit(0.3 + 2*ulp);
        testit(0.3 + 3*ulp);
    }

    private static void testit(double d) {
        System.out.println(d + " " + shortestBigDecimal(d) + " " + alternative(d));
    }

    private static BigDecimal shortestBigDecimal(double inputDouble) {
        double ulp = Math.ulp(inputDouble);
        String center = Double.toString(inputDouble);
        String high = Double.toString(inputDouble + ulp);
        String low = Double.toString(inputDouble - ulp);
        String high2 = Double.toString(inputDouble + ulp + ulp);
        String low2 = Double.toString(inputDouble - ulp - ulp);

        String shortest = minLength(minLength(minLength(minLength(low2, low), center), high), high2);
        return new BigDecimal(shortest);
    }

    private static String minLength(String a, String b) {
        return a.length() < b.length() ? a : b;
    }

    private static BigDecimal alternative(double d) {
        BigDecimal original = new BigDecimal(d);
        BigDecimal low = new BigDecimal(Math.nextDown(Math.nextDown(d)));
        BigDecimal high = new BigDecimal(Math.nextUp(Math.nextUp(d)));
        for(int scale = 0; scale <= original.scale(); scale++) {
            BigDecimal candidate = original.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
            if(candidate.compareTo(low) >= 0 && candidate.compareTo(high) <= 0) {
                return candidate;
            }
        }
        return original;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
0.1 0.1 0.1
1.15999999998 1.15999999998 1.15999999998
0.12000000000000001 0.12 0.12
100.00001 100.00001 100.00001
0.3 0.3 0.3
0.30000000000000004 0.3 0.3
0.3000000000000001 0.3 0.3
0.30000000000000016 0.3000000000000002 0.3000000000000002
```

Comment: Interesting approach. It does work as expected. Unfortunately, according to my (admittedly very limited) benchmark it seems to be slower than the toString() method, except in the cases where the expected number of decimals is 0.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs Performance could be improved by binary search, but not enough if it has to hit first try to equal the String method.